# Google Maps do not display correctly. Interpretation of error

Tags: google-maps, google-api

About three months ago I added my website on DigitalOcean. I bought the [template](https://htmlstream.com/preview/front-v2.9.2/html/pages/contacts-agency.html) from the official bootstrap site and added my variables along with the API Key generated from the Google platform in my template. My site look like this https://e-bluedesign.pl/kontakt/ .

About six days ago my Google maps stopped working completely and I can't restore them to their proper display.

Actions I did:

1. I generated the key and added it to my Bootstrap template
2. I activated all map services in my Google account panel along with JavaScript maps

Error which i see on my website (in console):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at common.js:70
    at Object._.jd (js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap:61)
    at a (common.js:70)
    at zp (common.js:70)
    at common.js:76
    at qp.i (common.js:150)
    at Object.c [as _uscq7q] (common.js:68)
    at QuotaService.RecordEvent?1shttps%3A%2F%2Fe-bluedesign.pl%2Fkontakt%2F&3sMY_API_KEY&7stlvq10&10e1&callback=_xdc_._uscq7q&key=MY_API_KEY&token=40296:1
```

I am trying to identify where such an unusual error occurred without my actions, hence the following questions:

1. Does Google anywhere provide information about where the error comes from? if so where?
2. Can the error come from not accepting the prepaid card in my Google payment system? If so, why was it accepted earlier, should Google not be notified by email? My Gmail service with my own domain also still works on the card I use for the API (and of course I never exceed the free budget that requires payment after crossing it).

Comment: Which [version](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions) of the API are you using? Did you try reverting the API version to an earlier version?  If that doesn't work, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue **in the question itself**, not (just) a link to an external site that exhibits the issue.

Comment: Looks like the [template](https://htmlstream.com/preview/front-v2.9.2/html/pages/contacts-agency.html) you bought is exhibiting the same error.  Perhaps you should ask the authors for a fix.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Google's disabling payments via prepaid cards. Although my Google Maps did not generate any costs. It was the lack of a current card that caused the map not being displayed.

I found more information here:
https://console.cloud.google.com/billing